# Downloading Files from FTP server - Ftp_fget Warning No such file or directory

Tags: php, ftp

Ok, Recently I have been working on code for my website to enable users that have logged in to download files that are on the server. I have got the users logging in fine. My problem is getting the ftp_fget() function to work. I have not only tried ftp_fget() but also ftp_get() amd ftp_nb_get().

How I have got it set up at the moment is on one page all the files in a certain directory are being displayed. I then added this

```
<a href="Replays/sc2_replays/ftp_download.php?file=<? echo "$filename" ?>"><input type="image" src="images/dl_icon.png" width="41" height="41"/></a>
```

When clicked it takes the user to the ftp_download.php page which is meant to download the chosen file.

Here is what I have got for the ftp_download page.

```
<?=
 $conn_id = ftp_connect("thomassawkins.hostoi.com","21") or die("could not connect");
 $ftp_login = ftp_login($conn_id,"USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
 $remote_file = $_GET['file'];
 $local_file = fopen("$remote_file",'w');

 ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 
    if(!$ftp_login)
    {
        echo "could not login";
    }
    else
    {

        if (ftp_fget($conn_id, $local_file, $remote_file, FTP_BINARY)){
            echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n"; 
            } else {
            echo "There was a problem\n"; 
            }
    }

    ftp_close($conn);
     ?>
```

When I click on the download button for the file I get this error after being directed to the download page

```
Warning: ftp_fget() [function.ftp-fget]: Can't open sc2 test - 2.txt: No such file or directory in /home/a5015247/public_html/Replays/sc2_replays/ftp_download.php on line 15
```

sc2 test - 2.txt is the test file I am trying to download. It is saved in the directory /home/a5015247/public_html/Replays/sc2_replays/

What I am trying to achieve overall is for the user to click on the desired file to download and then have it prompt the user where they are wanting to save the file on their machine.

Any help the solves my problems will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Thomas

--edit--
This is the code that displays all the files in the specified directory.

```
<?php
   $startdir = 'Replays/sc2_replays';
   $showthumbnails = false; 
   $showdirs = true;
   $forcedownloads = false;
   $hide = array(
            'dlf',
            'public_html',              
            'index.php',
            'Thumbs',
            '.htaccess',
            '.htpasswd'
        );
   $displayindex = false;
   $allowuploads = false;
   $overwrite = false;

   $indexfiles = array (
            'index.html',
            'index.htm',
            'default.htm',
            'default.html'
        );

          $filetypes = array (
            'png' => 'jpg.gif',
            'jpeg' => 'jpg.gif',
            'bmp' => 'jpg.gif',
            'jpg' => 'jpg.gif', 
            'gif' => 'gif.gif',
            'zip' => 'archive.png',
            'rar' => 'archive.png',
            'exe' => 'exe.gif',
            'setup' => 'setup.gif',
            'txt' => 'text.png',
            'htm' => 'html.gif',
            'html' => 'html.gif',
            'php' => 'php.gif',             
            'fla' => 'fla.gif',
            'swf' => 'swf.gif',
            'xls' => 'xls.gif',
            'doc' => 'doc.gif',
            'sig' => 'sig.gif',
            'fh10' => 'fh10.gif',
            'pdf' => 'pdf.gif',
            'psd' => 'psd.gif',
            'rm' => 'real.gif',
            'mpg' => 'video.gif',
            'mpeg' => 'video.gif',
            'mov' => 'video2.gif',
            'avi' => 'video.gif',
            'eps' => 'eps.gif',
            'gz' => 'archive.png',
            'asc' => 'sig.gif',
        );

         error_reporting(0);
         if(!function_exists('imagecreatetruecolor')) $showthumbnails = false;
         $leadon = $startdir;
         if($leadon=='Replays/sc2_replays') $leadon = '';
         if((substr($leadon, -1, 1)!='/') && $leadon!='') $leadon = $leadon . '/';
         $startdir = $leadon;


    if($_GET['dir']) {
//check this is okay.

if(substr($_GET['dir'], -1, 1)!='/') {
    $_GET['dir'] = $_GET['dir'] . '/';
}


$dirok = true;
$dirnames = split('/', $_GET['dir']);
for($di=0; $di<sizeof($dirnames); $di++) {


    if($di<(sizeof($dirnames)-2)) {
        $dotdotdir = $dotdotdir . $dirnames[$di] . '/';
    }


    if($dirnames[$di] == '..') {
        $dirok = false;
    }
}


if(substr($_GET['dir'], 0, 1)=='/') {
    $dirok = false;
}


if($dirok) {
     $leadon = $leadon . $_GET['dir'];
}
    }


    $opendir = $leadon;
    if(!$leadon) $opendir = 'Replays/sc2_replays/';
    if(!file_exists($opendir)) {
$opendir = 'Replays/sc2_replays/';
$leadon = $startdir;
    }

    clearstatcache();
    if ($handle = opendir($opendir)) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
    //first see if this file is required in the listing
    if ($file == "." || $file == "..")  continue;
    $discard = false;
    for($hi=0;$hi<sizeof($hide);$hi++) {
        if(strpos($file, $hide[$hi])!==false) {
            $discard = true;
        }
    }

    if($discard) continue;
    if (@filetype($leadon.$file) == "dir") {
        if(!$showdirs) continue;    

        $n++;
        if($_GET['sort']=="date") {
            $key = @filemtime($leadon.$file) . ".$n";
        }
        else {
            $key = $n;
        }
        $dirs[$key] = $file . "/";
    }
    else {
        $n++;
        if($_GET['sort']=="date") {
            $key = @filemtime($leadon.$file) . ".$n";
        }
        elseif($_GET['sort']=="size") {
            $key = @filesize($leadon.$file) . ".$n";
        }
        else {
            $key = $n;
        }
        $files[$key] = $file;           

        if($displayindex) {
            if(in_array(strtolower($file), $indexfiles)) {
                header("Location: $file");
                die();
            }
        }
    }
}
closedir($handle); 
    }

    //sort our files
    if($_GET['sort']=="date") {
@ksort($dirs, SORT_NUMERIC);
@ksort($files, SORT_NUMERIC);
     }
    elseif($_GET['sort']=="size") {
@natcasesort($dirs); 
@ksort($files, SORT_NUMERIC);
   }
    else {
@natcasesort($dirs); 
@natcasesort($files);
    }

   //order correctly
   if($_GET['order']=="desc" && $_GET['sort']!="size") {$dirs = @array_reverse($dirs);}
   if($_GET['order']=="desc") {$files = @array_reverse($files);}
   $dirs = @array_values($dirs); $files = @array_values($files);

   ?>
   <div id="listingcontainer">
    <div id="listingheader"> 
<div id="headerfile"></div> 
<div id="headersize"></div>
<div id="headermodified"></div>
    </div>
       <div id="listing">
        <?
       $class = 'b';
       if($dirok) {
?>
  <div><a href="<?=$dotdotdir;?>" class="<?=$class;?>"><img src="http://www.000webhost.com/images/index/dirup.png" alt="Folder" /><strong>..</strong> <em>-</em> <?=date ("M d Y h:i:s A", filemtime($dotdotdir));?></a></div>

<?
    if($class=='b') $class='w';
    else $class = 'b';
}
$arsize = sizeof($dirs);
for($i=0;$i<$arsize;$i++) {
?>
<div><a href="<?=$leadon.$dirs[$i];?>" class="<?=$class;?>"><img             src="http://www.000webhost.com/images/index/folder.png" alt="<?=$dirs[$i];?>" /><strong><?=$dirs[$i];?></strong> <em>-</em> <?=date ("M d Y h:i:s A", filemtime($leadon.$dirs[$i]));?></a></div>
<?
    if($class=='b') $class='w';
    else $class = 'b';  
}


$arsize = sizeof($files);
for($i=0;$i<$arsize;$i++) {
    $icon = 'unknown.png';
    $ext = strtolower(substr($files[$i], strrpos($files[$i], '.')+1));
    $supportedimages = array('gif', 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg');
    $thumb = '';


    if($filetypes[$ext]) {
        $icon = $filetypes[$ext];
    }

    $filename = $files[$i];
    if(strlen($filename)>43) {
        $filename = substr($files[$i], 0, 40) . '...';
    }

    $fileurl = $leadon . $files[$i];
?>
<div>
  <table width="574" border="0.5" align="center">
    <tr>
      <th width="59" align="center" valign="middle" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
      <th width="136" align="center" valign="middle" scope="col"><img src="http://www.000webhost.com/images/index/<?=$icon;?>" alt="<?=$files[$i];?>" /><strong><?=$filename;?></strong>
      </a></th>
      <th width="101" align="center" valign="middle" scope="col"><em>
        <?=round(filesize($leadon.$files[$i])/1024);?>
        KB</em></a></th>
      <th width="186" align="center" valign="middle" scope="col">
        <?=date ("M d Y h:i:s A", filemtime($leadon.$files[$i]));?>
        </a></th>
        <th width="70" align="right" valign="middle" scope="col">
      <a href="ftp_download.php?filedir=<? echo "./$opendir"?>"><input type="image" src="images/dl_icon.png" width="41" height="41"/></a>

        </a></th>
    </tr>
  </table> 
</div>
<?
    if($class=='b') $class='w';
    else $class = 'b';  
}   
?></div>
```

What happens is when the user clicks the icon here

```
<a href="ftp_download.php?filedir=<? echo "./$opendir"?>"><input type="image" src="images/dl_icon.png" width="41" height="41"/></a>
```

They are then redirected to download.php which handles the download part of it. At the moment I am not even able to successfully change the directory using chdir for some reason. the error that I get is

```
Warning: ftp_chdir() [function.ftp-chdir]: Can't change directory to /Replays/sc2_replays/: No such file or directory in /home/a5015247/public_html/ftp_download.php on line 15
```

the file dumby file that I am trying to download is in the directory public_html/Replays/sc2_replay/dumby.txt.

I also user ftp_pwd to find out what directory I am currently in when i get this error and it outputs "/". Im not sure what that means

```
ftp_chdir($conn_id, "/Replays/sc2_replays/");
        echo ftp_pwd($conn_id);
```

Regards,

Thomas

Comment: Well, you gave the wrong filename. Obviously. Use `ftp_chdir` first to get into the *right* folder. You are *not* in the right folder (check with `ftp_pwd`). Also would be easier by just using `copy("ftp://server.name/folder/sc2", "./sc2.txt");` -- Anyway, too localized, too few details to help you here.

Comment: I have tried using ftp_chdir to get it into the right directory but even that is not working. All I got was this `Warning: ftp_chdir() [function.ftp-chdir]: Can't change directory to /home/a5015247/public_html/testing/testing/: No such file or directory in /home/a5015247/public_html/ftp_download.php on line 15` and the directory is says it cant change to is there i tripple checked it and that file path is there. I have edited my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Path name is wrong. If you don't specify a path after connecting, it's going to look in the base directory. You can either use `ftp_chdir` to change in to the directory, or you can prepend the path to the file you're trying to download (i.e. './folder/subfolder/file.jpg');

Also, just from looking at your script, depending on how you've configure it, there's potentially a huge security flaw. You're trusting the user to input `$_GET['file']` safely, which isn't the smartest thing to do. You'll probably want to limit the files to certain directories (unless you're connecting to a file server and really do want them to be able to download anything).